# Can't connect to web server from outside my network

Tags: networking, router, iptables, apache-http-server

I have a Debian-based server that I would like to be able to access from the Internet (no domain name yet, I'm just trying to get it working for now).

I already have port forwarding set up on my router to forward inbound http connections to port 80 on 192.168.2.10 (my server address). My SSH service is set up the same way on port 22.  I called my ISP about this yesterday and they assured me that both 80 and 22 are able to accept incoming connections on my current plan (so they aren't blocking it).  I have a static IP and I've been able to SSH in from anywhere ever since I set the server up.

I know Apache is running because I can type `http://192.168.2.10` from any computer on my network and get there just fine. However, trying access from outside my network (`http://[my public ip address]`) doesn't work--the connection just times out.

I suspect that a firewall might have something to do with this but I'm not entirely sure. Oddly, my Iptables seems to be blank (output of iptables -L):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is the Nmap report for 192.168.2.10:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
143/tcp  open  imap
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
901/tcp  open  samba-swat
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
3000/tcp open  ppp
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
5910/tcp open  cm
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

Comment: Are you Port Forwarding port 80 as TCP or UDP?

Comment: It's currently set on TCP.